# FTP upload failed

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

I have a bash script that backs up my iOS files over FTP and I'm getting a few problems, I'm just wondering if anyone could help me out?

Here's my script:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  mkdir zipfolder
  cp /var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db /var/root/zipfolder/
  cp /var/mobile/Library/Notes/notes.sqlite /var/root/zipfolder/
  cp /var/mobile/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.db /var/root/zipfolder/
  cp /var/mobile/Library/Safari/History.plist /var/root/zipfolder/
  cd var/root
  zip -r zippyy.zip zipfolder

  HOST=HOSTNAME
  USER=USERNAME
  PASS=PASSWORD

  ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
  user $USER $PASS
  cd sms
  LIST=$(ls | grep zippyy*.zip)

  FILECOUNT=0
  for FILE in $LIST
  do
      if [ -f $FILE ];
      then
          FILECOUNT+=1
  done
  FILECOUNT+=1
  NEXTDB="zippyy$FILECOUNT.db"
  mv zippyy.zip $NEXTDB

  ftp -inv $HOST << EOF    
  put $NEXTDB
  bye
  EOF

  rm -f zippyy.zip
  rmdir zipfolder
```

I get the following errors:

```
  ?Invalid command
  ?Invalid command
  We only support non-print format, sorry.
  ?Invalid command
  ?Invalid command
  ?Invalid command
  ?Invalid command
  ?Invalid command
  ?Invalid command
  ?Invalid command
  ?Invalid command
  ?Invalid command
  (local-file) (remote-file)

  rmdir: failed to remove 'zipfolder': Not a directory
```

Comment: Also, i'm trying to run this as root, is there a way that I could run the script without su?

Comment: Try "set -x" as the second line of your script, it will make debugging much easier. You can turn it off with "set +x".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer #3 for formatting

Try something like this (totally untested!)

```
#!/bin/bash

ROOTFOLDER="/var/root"
ZIPNAME="zipfolder"
ZIPFOLDER=$ROOTFOLDER/$ZIPNAME
LIBFOLDER="/var/mobile/Library"
ZIPFILE="zippyy.zip"

mkdir -p $ZIPFOLDER
cp $LIBFOLDER/SMS/sms.db $ZIPFOLDER/
cp $LIBFOLDER/Notes/notes.sqlite $ZIPFOLDER/
cp $LIBFOLDER/Safari/Bookmarks.db $ZIPFOLDER/
cp $LIBFOLDER/Safari/History.plist $ZIPFOLDER/
cd $ROOTFOLDER
zip -r $ZIPFILE $ZIPNAME

HOST=HOSTNAME
USER=USERNAME
PASS=PASSWORD

ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
user $USER $PASS
cd sms
dir . remote_dir.txt
bye
EOF

FILECOUNT=$(grep zippyy remote_dir.txt | wc -l)
NEXTDB="zippyy${FILECOUNT}.db"
mv $ZIPFILE $NEXTDB

ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
user $USER $PASS
put $NEXTDB
bye
EOF
```

Comment: Almost helped, but instead of the zip file, I get a .db file uploaded to the FTP Directory instead? The code is brilliant though, thanks :)

Comment: Glad it helped :-) . The db file is from the line "mv zippyy.zip $NEXTDB" in your original code - it renames the zip file to a .db file. I dont know why you'd want to do that, but it was in your code so I copied it! Perhaps you should change it to: NEXTDB="zippyy${FILECOUNT}.zip"

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using cp -i in a script? The -i switch makes the copy "interactive" and so is expecting input from the user, which it wont get because of the script.

Also, can you format your script using the "Code sample" format rather than bullet points! ;-)

Comment: Sorted the Copy problem out, now it's just the invalid commands. Any help anyone? Yes, I'll remember to next time, I'm new here

Comment: In your command "LIST=$(ls | grep zippyy*.zip)" you cant guarantee that the zip file will be the only file listed on that line - any other junk files could be on the same line. Try using "ls -1" to force a single file per line of output.

Comment: Also, your first ftp command doesnt have a terminating EOF line - so everything between the ftp command and the final EOF is actually running inside an ftp session!

Comment: I'm a real 'noob' at writing bash haha. Would it be possible if you could re-write that script for me please? I would be VERY grateful! Thank you sir :)

Answer (score 0):

New answer for formatting...

It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do. It looks like you're trying to find out how many existing backups there are on the ftp server and rename the new backup to go at the end of the list.

You cant execute code on an ftp server (massive security hole!) so the best way to do accomplish this would probably be to get the remote directory listing and process it locally. Try using something like:

```
  ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
  user $USER $PASS
  cd sms
  dir . remote_dir.txt
  bye
  EOF
```

{process remote_dir.txt now to get new backup name}

```
  ftp -inv $HOST << EOF    
  user $USER $PASS
  put $NEXTDB
  bye
  EOF
```

Comment: Hey again, I'm struggling a bit haha, where would I place this is my script above? I'm sorry, I'm still a noob haha